# How to solve the path conflicts in two jar

Tags: scala, sbt, dependency-management, conflicting-libraries

I have two jars with same class path:
jar1: com.xxx.events.EventFamily, com.yyy.OtherClass1
jar2: com.xxx.events.EventFamily, com.yyy.OtherClass2

I want to keep them both in my project and jar2 overwrite the same class(`com.xxx.events.EventFamily`) in jar1, and I can still use other class(com.yyy.OtherClass1) in jar1.

I tried
`.settings(dependencyOverrides ++= Seq("com.xxx" %% "jar2" % Version.jar2))`

But it didn't work.

Comment: 1st, that's bad practice to have same class in two JARs. However if they are the same, you don't have to do anything, it should run without issue. If they are NOT, you'll have to do some filtering/shading. `dependencyOverrides` is meant for specifying specific version of a JAR, not a class.